# make oldconfig for entry without prompt

Tags: linux-kernel, kbuild

I'm doing a `make oldconfig` on a config file that has `CONFIG_FOO=y`.   The kconfig entry defines `FOO` as a `bool`, without a prompt.   It seems that make oldconfig wipes out the entry.    If I add a prompt to `FOO`, then the value is retained.  I'm guessing this is the expected behavior, but I'm not finding any documentation that states that this is how it should work.   Can someone confirm that this is what is supposed to happen?

(the kconfig file looks like:)

```
config FOO
    bool
```

Comment: A prompt-less config option is assumed to be unset unless some other config option selects it.

Comment: Would you have a source for that?

Comment: See the section Defaults on page 4 and 5 of [Formal Semantics of the Kconfig Language](http://www.eng.uwaterloo.ca/~shshe/kconfig_semantics.pdf). I should also have mentioned that explicit default values for each config option can be specified as part of the Kconfig language.